# What's the thought process for the solution of this logical riddle?

Tags: logic, puzzle

> Mr. Carter, Mr. Flynn, Mr. Milne, and Mr. Savage serve the little town
> of Milford as architect, banker, druggist, and grocer, though not
> necessarily respectively. Each man's income is a whole number of
> dollars.
>
> The druggist earns exactly twice as much as the grocer, the architect
> earns exactly twice as much as the druggist, and the banker earns
> exactly twice as much as the architect.
>
> Although Mr. Carter does not make more moneythan Mr. Flynn, Mr. Flynn
> does not make twice as much as Mr. Carter. Mr. Savage earns exactly
> $3776 more than Mr. Milne.
>
> What is each man occupation?

Riddle from 101 Puzzles in Thought and Logic.
The book provides the following solution:
Carter is the grocer,Flynn the banker, Milne the druggist, and Savage the architect.

---

UPDATE: My approach, really by trial and error:

Being: G=g, D=2g, A=4g, B=8g

given: C<F ^ F≠2C
then: F=4C ∨ F=8C, also as F=4g ∨ F=8g

if C=g and F=8g

given: S-M=3776
then: 4g-2g=3776

so: S=A and M=D

Apologies for the math notation certainly not perfect.
If someone has a more 'elegant' way, please add.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Factoring $3776$ helps.

Comment: If the grocer makes $g$, the incomes are $g,2g,4g,8g$.  Flynn and Carter are not next to each other in the list.

Comment: " Flynn does not make twice as much as Mr. Carter " is a bit ambiguous. Does it mean that $F \neq 2 C$ or that $F \le 2C$?

Comment: @Lulu I didn't go very far unfortunately. Just one step after the definitions.

Comment: @JustANoob none has the same salary

Comment: The factoring hint is close to a full solution.  $3776=2^6\times 59$.  to use that, suppose, say, that Savage was the banker and Milne the grocer.  Then we'd get that $8g-g=7g=3776$  But $7$ does not divide $3776$, so that is impossible.  Continue in this spirit.

Comment: @Lulu many thanks for the pointer.